# Groupby then make columns from unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to find the answer to this:

So I have a large dataset with a column for Category (TCFM, BLE, IA&C, and II&T).

I want to know how I can create new columns for each Category ('TCFM', 'IA&C', nan, 'II&T', 'BLE'). Keeping all the original data?

```
Product Views    Revenue    SEO Entries    Category 
32               -123.29        5          TCFM
6                  91.55        1          IA&C
```

This goes on for 4000 rows

`grouped = impact.groupby('Category')`

I know I need to group it, but not sure how to implement it into the Dataframe.

So basically adding four columns onto the original dataframe

Comment: like `dummy` colunmns? `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Category'])`?

Comment: Well i want to do Kmeans test on the individual categories rather than all together.

Comment: Or pivot table maybe, using ['Categories'] as columns

Comment: What is your expected output from the sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this?

Converting

```
   Product Views  Revenue  SEO Entries Category
0             53       19           73      BLE
1             41       56           52     TCFM
2              5       92           36     None
3             18       57           38     II&T
4             92       15           92     II&T
```

to

```
   Product Views  Revenue  SEO Entries   TCFM   IA&C    NaN   II&T    BLE
0             53       19           73  False  False  False  False   True
1             41       56           52   True  False  False  False  False
2              5       92           36  False  False  False  False  False
3             18       57           38  False  False  False   True  False
4             92       15           92  False  False  False   True  False
```

Code to generate the example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

categories = ['TCFM', 'IA&C', None, 'II&T', 'BLE']
cols = ['Product Views', 'Revenue', 'SEO Entries', 'Category']

data = {}
for i in range(3):
    data[cols[i]] = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10)

data['Category'] = random.choices(categories, k=10)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df.head())
```

Code which generate the new columns

```py
for item in categories:
    df[item] = np.where(df.Category == item, True, False)

df1 = df.drop(['Category'], axis=1)
print(df1.head())
```

This line creates the new column for each `category` item.
`df[item] = np.where(df.Category == item, True, False)`

It sets the value to `True` if value of the `Category` column is equal to item, else to `False`
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a bit of info as to what each stage is. I am fairly new to Python. This is what i am wanting though.

Comment: the i for range bit, doesnt seem to work - ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: may be you are having different values for the columns list. Change `for i in range(3)` to `for in range(len(df.columns)-1)`

Comment: do i even need to do that if that is you creating a dataframe. Do i just need to do the code that generates the new columns? This is a great help, thanks

Comment: As the code to generate new columns is saying: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Category' for item in categories:
  `impact[item] = np.where(impact.Category == item, True, False)
    
impact1 = impact.drop(['Category'], axis=1)
impact1. head()`

Comment: cant seem to get the categories to split out

Comment: `df.drop` generates a new dataframe. you must assign the result to another variable.

Comment: or you must set the argument `inplace` to `True`